# Cannot find the correct syntax to access a nested div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to access a specific div but without success. It is a nested div within a list. I would like to add some style on it.

none of the below jquery work

```js
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#st2').attr('style', '');
    $('div#st2').attr('style', 'display: block;');
    $('#st2').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
    $('#st2').attr('style', 'height: 360.6px;')
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="st-ul" class="st-ul">
  <li id="li2" runat="server">
    <a href="#" class="pane">Test Page<span class="st-arrow" /></a>
    <div id="st2" class="st-content">
      <h2>
        <asp:Label ID="TitleLbl" runat="server" Text="" />
      </h2>
      <asp:Label ID="LMessageLbl" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
  </li>
  </u>
```

When I do inspect element I can see that the style for div #st2 is not applied. What is the correct syntax to access div #st2 ?

Comment: did you call `pageLoad` function ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accessing the div fine, but I think you're applying the css incorrectly. Use the `css` method instead of the `attr` method. Something like:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var $st2 = $('#st2');
  console.log('#st2', $st2);
  $st2.css('display','block');
  $st2.css('height','360.6px');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="st-ul" class="st-ul">
  <li id="li2" runat="server">
    <a href="#" class="pane">Test Page<span class="st-arrow" /></a>
    <div id="st2" class="st-content">
      <h2>
        <asp:Label ID="TitleLbl" runat="server" Text="" />
      </h2>
      <asp:Label ID="LMessageLbl" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
  </li>
  </u>
```

Comment: FYI both `.attr('style')` and `.css(props)` work the same with `.css` with a notable difference that `.css` can get/set single or multiple properties where `attr` will override the attribute as a whole. Though that's neither the issue or solution at hand.

Comment: thank you guys for your replies. However, it looks like by default the div #st2 has an inherited style attribute display: none; which I cannot override it with the above code. It's always rendering like style="display: none; height: 360.7px;"

Comment: for example $st2.css('style', 'display: block !important'); does not work either, it is still style="height: 360.77px; display: none;"